# C# send HTTP request on Windows Shutdown / Logout event

Tags: c#, shutdown

I want to send a HTTP Post request whenever the OS requests a shutdown, but for some reason the HTTP is not being sent. I've tried to save the same data to a file using `File.WriteAllTextAsync` and that works. I've also tried creating a service and a console app. For whatever reason all the documentation I found refers to just cancelling the shutdown/logoff but that's not what I need. I need the shutdown to await until the the HTTP request returns 200.

The thing is that I've put the HTTP request in a try-catch and issued the catch to write the exception into the console and to a File. The file is never written in the catch block so I'm assuming the try block is working.

This might be a timing issue, that the  system shuts down just before ending the request, but I'ts actually very hard to debug cause... well the system just shuts down every time I make any attempt.

The application is an WPF app. This is the main App.xaml.cs:

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        static readonly HttpClient client = new();
        async void App_SessionEnding(object sender, SessionEndingCancelEventArgs ev)
        {
            var evento = new Evento(Environment.UserName, Environment.MachineName, DateTime.Now, "Logout", "some-data");
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(evento);
            var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("some-url",data);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                await File.WriteAllTextAsync("WriteLines.txt", responseBody);
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException e)
            {
                await File.WriteAllTextAsync("WriteLines.txt", ev.ReasonSessionEnding.ToString());
                 Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");
                Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ", e.Message);
                await File.WriteAllTextAsync("WriteLines.txt", await data.ReadAsStringAsync());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And his refering App.xaml:

```
<Application 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="WpfApp1.App"
    ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown"             
    StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
    SessionEnding="App_SessionEnding" />
```

The MainWindow.xaml is an empty window with Visibility hidden. It doesnt even matter what I do to this window,I've put it on show, on hidden, I even tried fullscreen.

Comment: Async event handlers are *not* being awaited, which means the application can terminate before the HTTP call had a chance to even start executing.What are you trying to do in the first place? A desktop app is the most insecure way to try to detect OS events. A Windows Service would be better but even so, Windows already has mechanisms to log OS events - the event log. Windows Event Forwarding and Event Collector features can forward specific events to a central Event Collector machine. You can specify the forwarding subscription settings through group policy, without installing anything

Comment: [Setting up a Source Initiated Subscription](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wec/setting-up-a-source-initiated-subscription) shows how you can create a Subscription policy and apply it on multiple computers. [Use Windows Event Forwarding to help with intrusion detection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/use-windows-event-forwarding-to-assist-in-intrusion-detection) contains the event subscriptions used to track suspicious activities. APM tools like Elastic and Splunk can ingest forwarded events directly instead of using their own clients

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you for your response. My company asked me to do an app to track hours, so they can control if extra hours are made, so I'm sending the shutdown hour to a server to have a database of the hours they shut down the pc.

Comment: Please, read this: [detecting if a Windows shutdown command has been issued](https://superuser.com/questions/590434/detecting-if-a-windows-shutdown-command-has-been-issued)

Comment: Then you **don't** need real-time events at all. Just reading the forwarded events will be more than enough, even if they're delayed by a few hours. And you **do** want to be able to deploy the subscriptions without installing agents

Comment: @MaciejLos the `SessionEnding` event is already doing the detection. It's the message that isn't being sent

Comment: Okay, I will use the documentation you've sent me and try to make event forwarding. Thanks! Another fast question, can I forward the events to a SQL database? Or to my crud API

Comment: If you want to test this as it is, you could suspend the shutdown handling the `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` message and calling [ShutdownBlockReasonCreate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-shutdownblockreasoncreate). The block reason is presented to the User. This supersedes `App_SessionEnding`. Close the Window when you're done and call `ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy` (it should also be called when `WM_ENDSESSION` is received. -- You can then test whether the Network is still working at that point. You could also cancel the shutdown (while testing).

Comment: @SebastianCiocarlan WEF was introduced in 2008, which means the *nice* blogs that explain how it works were written 13 years ago and got mixed up or lost their image links after several Microsoft site redesigns. What you need is to setup up the WEF subscriptions and on the collector machine, set up an Event Reader service that writes the events you want in a database. Luckily, there's a `4sysops` article that shows how to do this : [Windows Event Forwarding to a SQL database](https://4sysops.com/archives/windows-event-forwarding-to-a-sql-database/)

Comment: That will do @PanagiotisKanavos thank you very much! I'm reading the documentation you've handled and now I see that my approach was reduntant. The problem was that I didnt even thought that there would be a windows native way of doing this, so I just assumed that I would have to do everything myself.

Comment: @SebastianCiocarlan [Importing Windows Forwarded Events into SQL Server using PowerShell](https://blog.netnerds.net/2013/03/importing-windows-forwarded-events-into-sql-server-using-powershell/) explains how to import the forwarded events. You can do the same in C# using the [EventLogReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb671200(v=vs.90)) class, or listen for real-time events with [EventLogWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb671202(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: @SebastianCiocarlan unlike Linux or Mac, Windows was built from the start to allow managing *several* thousands of client computers and devices on a network, from a few central (domain controller) servers. The APIs are pretty standardized, WS-Management, WS-Eventing etc. Most of the jobs done using Puppet or Parrot are already available as features on Windows. What Windows doesn't do well is managing hundreds of unrelated servers, each with unique configuration and settings, like the ones you'd find in a web farm or service cluster.

Comment: Okay so @PanagiotisKanavos I've created a subscription and configured the event forwarding subscription group policy as explained [here](https://4sysops.com/archives/windows-event-forwarding-to-a-sql-database/) but I get 0 source computers connected to the subscription. I've used Domain Computers group and then checked that all the company computers appear on the group (they do appear). I configured it through http with SERVER=sqdn (I get the SQDN from the system properties, and used the full name like this "ListenerComputer.nameOfTheDomain"), yet I don't get any Source Team subscribed.

Comment: Oh and I got Security and System from Windows as the event logs, with ids 1074,6006,6008,4647. Any idea? Where should I direct my problems? Maybe to another Stack?